# Applying GRS-test on non-normal residuals with autocorrelation

Tags: asset-pricing, econometrics

Is it valid to apply GRS-test ([Gibbons, Ross and Shanken 1989](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/ecmemetrp/v_3a57_3ay_3a1989_3ai_3a5_3ap_3a1121-52.htm)) on non-normal and autocorrelated residuals?

I got residuals using 10 test-assets regressed on 3-factor and carhart.

If it is valid, how should I do it?

And if it is not valid, what should we do?